# Connect to program's hotspot programmatically

Tags: java, android-networking

In my program there is two ability

1. create hotspot
2. connect to this hotspot

I install this program on two different device. a Samsung gallaxyS2 and a HTC oneM8 . there is no problem in creating hotspot .if I create hotspot on Samsung gallaxyS2 ,I can connect to it with HTC oneM8 easily , but if I create hotspot on HTC oneM8 and try to connect with Samsung gallaxyM8 , the addNetwork Function return -1 .
this is my connecting code :

```
private void JoinToNetWork(){
    ScanResult AP= scanAP();
    if (AP!=null){
        try{
            txt.setText("Hotspot named ''" + AP.SSID +"'' is found !  \n");
            wConfig=new WifiConfiguration();
            wConfig.SSID=AP.SSID;
            wConfig.allowedKeyManagement.set(WifiConfiguration.KeyMgmt.NONE);
            wConfig.allowedProtocols.set(WifiConfiguration.Protocol.RSN);
            wConfig.allowedProtocols.set(WifiConfiguration.Protocol.WPA);
            wConfig.allowedAuthAlgorithms.clear();
            wConfig.allowedPairwiseCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.PairwiseCipher.CCMP);
            wConfig.allowedPairwiseCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.PairwiseCipher.TKIP);
            wConfig.allowedGroupCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.GroupCipher.WEP40);
            wConfig.allowedGroupCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.GroupCipher.WEP104);
            wConfig.allowedGroupCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.GroupCipher.CCMP);
            wConfig.allowedGroupCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.GroupCipher.TKIP);
            int NetId=wfMgr.addNetwork(wConfig);
            try{
                txt.append("Disconnect : " + wfMgr.disconnect() +"\n");
                txt.append("Enabling network ... " + wfMgr.enableNetwork(NetId, true) + "\n");
                txt.append("Reconnect to " + AP.BSSID + "/" + AP.SSID + ".... " + wfMgr.reconnect() + "\n");
                wfMgr.setWifiEnabled(true);
                txt.append("connected");
            }catch(Exception e){
                txt.setText(e.toString());
            }
        }catch(Exception e){
            Toast.makeText(this.getBaseContext(), e.getMessage()+"..."+e.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }else 
        Toast.makeText(this.getBaseContext(), "There is no BluffGame AccessPoint",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: The question is : what is the reason of returning -1 from addNetwork function , if and only if i try to connect to hotspot created on my HTC one M8 via my Samsung galaxy S2 through my code ? But if I try to connect to hotspot created on Samsung galaxy S2 with HTC one M8 with code above everything is ok. Why this happen?